# setTheme(R.style.MyTheme) does not work with Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am learning about designing app theme according to [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

At first, in AndroidManifest, I used

```xml
<activity android:theme="@android:style/MyTheme">
```

and then I got the result showing that UI thread had to do too much work so it skipped some of my frames. Then I thought about setting theme programmatically
by using Thread but it did not work, either.

My custom theme

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="MyTheme"
    parent="android:Theme.Material" >

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>

</style>
```

My main activity xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context="com.example.material_theme.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

My java code

```
package com.example.material_theme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
            }

        }).start();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only can set theme before `setContentView`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

In your case you might want to use this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
                setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }, 100);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

PS: You don't need multi threading in this case. All stuff could be done in main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately, I still couldn't get what I want. I don't know whether my problem has something to deal with backward compatibility or not. My virtual device I used is API 19. I thought import support file, everything would be okay. Is my suspicion possible?

Comment: @FantasticSky You are using the _default_ theme of any Android version installed on devices. Since every themes extending `android:Theme` refers to the default theme installed on that device. But you should know that this default theme varies from version to version. Thus, your problem has nothing to do with backward compatibility and such. Unfortunately I still could not understand what would you want to achieve.

Comment: Oh so I learned something new. My purpose is to change the color primary by inheriting Theme.Material. In fact, even I used thread, either your way or my way, the color primary does not change.

Comment: @FantasticSky I can't understand why would you like to set theme at run-time? You can set it in manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this once

Running the thread before the activity calls the superclass

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(100);
    }
}).start();
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately I couldn't get what I want. Do you think the reason is that I only use virtual device with API 19? At first I thought, importing support files in extras is enough. Is it the problem?

Comment: First try and see if the theme works in a normal way. Then check if the thread works normally. Lastly, add the Thread without the setTheme, just so that you can pause for 100 ms, and then after the thread declaration is over, call the setTheme. (Edited the answer)
I always recommend testing on a real device and implementing a try and catch wherever you think it's risky.
Let me know if it works out.

Comment: I think the use of thread is fine, either my way or your way,  but the thing is that I did not see any changes on color primary, which is what i am trying to do.

Comment: I strongly recommend testing the theme singularly. Now I know why we were constantly told about Unit Testing back in college.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. This will pause the main thread for given time.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```